# How to change React Time Range Picker min or max values on certain action

Tags: reactjs

I am using `react-ts-timepicker` with `minTime 08:00:00`, and I want to change the min value each time I change the selected date, but, the react time picker's min value remains the same as initialized in the beginning.

When I `setState` the new time value, only the react time picker's value changes and the `minTime` doesn't.

This is for today's data:

[image: This is for today's data]

And for other days, `minTime` remains at 8am:

[image: And for other days, minTime remains at 8am]

Here is part of the code

```
<ReactTimePicker
      value={this.state.selectedTime}
      minTime={this.state.minTime}
      maxTime="23:00:00"
      step={60}
      onChange={this.handleChangeTime}
    />
```

The function that changes the time values,

```
this.setState({
      selectedTime: "02:00:00",
      minTime: "11:00:00" })
```

Comment: Please post a small re-producible example of your code so we can help you.

Comment: I edited the question, you can check now.

Comment: That is not enough to help you. I assume you will have to hoist the state further up your tree. That's all I can see from here.

Comment: Or do you think that minTime attribute is static and can't be changed not as the value attribute? or it's not the case